# Ruby on Rails Routes: Namespace with more params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

i have a namespace "shop". In that namespace i have a resource "news".

```
namespace :shop do
  resources :news  
end
```

What i now need, is that my "news" route can get a new parameter:

```
/shop/nike (landing page -> goes to "news#index", :identifier => "nike")
/shop/adidas (landing page -> goes to "news#index", :identifier => "adidas")
/shop/nike/news
/shop/adidas/news
```

So that i can get the shop and filter my news.

I need a route like:

```
/shop/:identfier/:controller/:action/:id
```

I tested many variations but i cant get it running.

Anyone can get me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the names of these pages before-hand or do you need to generate them from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have those nike, adidas etc. in the database then the most straightforward option is to use match.

```
namespace :shop
  match "/:shop_name" => "news#index"
  match "/:shop_name/news" => "news#news"
end
```

However it seems to me that shop should be a resource for you. Just create a ShopsController (you don't need a matching model for it, just a controller). Then you can do

```
resources :shops, :path => "/shop"
  resources :news
end
```

Now you can access the news index page (/shop/adidas) like this:

```
shop_path("adidas")
```

In the NewsController use `:shop_id` to access the name of the shop (yes even though it's _id it can be a string). Depending on your setup you may want news to be a singular resource, or the news method to be a collection method.

Also are you sure just renaming the news resource isn't something you want?

```
resources :news, :path => "/shop" do
  get "news"
end
```

Keep in mind also that controller names and the number of controllers need not match your models. For example you can have a News model without a NewsController and a ShopsController without a Shop model. You might even consider adding a Shop model to your database if that makes sense.
In case this is not your setup then you might have oversimplified your example and you should provide a more full description of your setup.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `scope`.

```
scope "/shops/:identifier", :as => "shop" do
  resources :news
end
```

You will get those routes below:

```
$ rake routes
shop_news_index GET    /shops/:identifier/news(.:format)          news#index
                POST   /shops/:identifier/news(.:format)          news#create
  new_shop_news GET    /shops/:identifier/news/new(.:format)      news#new
 edit_shop_news GET    /shops/:identifier/news/:id/edit(.:format) news#edit
      shop_news GET    /shops/:identifier/news/:id(.:format)      news#show
                PUT    /shops/:identifier/news/:id(.:format)      news#update
                DELETE /shops/:identifier/news/:id(.:format)      news#destroy
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing